# User control with custom properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a UserControl which is a legend of a graph item,
I've defined it so it has a label with the graph name, a check box which
define whether we show it or not and a rectangle with the graph color.

The xaml is defined like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Resources.LegendItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="1,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="cb" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsGraphVisible}" >
                    <StackPanel Margin="1,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Name="rec" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Height="10" Width="10" />
                        <Label Name="lab" Content="{TemplateBinding GraphName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

and the cs file is:

```
namespace Resources
{
    public partial class LegendItem : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsGraphVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsGraphVisible", typeof(Boolean), typeof(LegendItem));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GraphNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GraphName", typeof(String), typeof(LegendItem));

        public bool IsGraphVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsGraphVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsGraphVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        public string GraphName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(GraphNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GraphNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public LegendItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

But when I compile it, I get an error "Cannot find the static member 'IsGraphVisibleProperty' on the type 'Control'."
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a template at all. `UserControl` allows the XAML to be declared directly. You can't set the template in a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Resources.LegendItem" x:Name="MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">

        <StackPanel Margin="1,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="cb" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=IsGraphVisible}" >
                <StackPanel Margin="1,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Name="rec" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Height="10" Width="10" />
                    <Label Name="lab" Content="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=GraphName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `TargetType="{x:Type Resources.LegendItem}"` on your `ControlTemplate`, otherwise it defaults to being a template for `Control` and you get that error.

Comment: By the way, why is it a template for Control instead of UserControl?

Comment: Because Control is the most general control that can be templated. The Template property first appears in Control.

Comment: UserControls do not allow the template to be set.