# Binding custom Dependency Property on User Control with ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've created a custom button with a `ControlTemplate`.
I used a `ControlTemplate` to make it possible to bind the default properties of `UserControl`, such as `Background` or `Foreground`.

But, if I add custom dependency properties (for example `CornerRadius`) I get two errors:

1. *"The member 'CornerRadius' is not recognized or is not accessible."*
2. *"Cannot find the static member 'CornerRadiusProperty' on the type 'UserControl'."*

**Xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50"
         BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black"
         Content="OK" Foreground="White">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Border Name="ground"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                <Label Name="content"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                       FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class MyButton : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(MyButton));

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }


        public MyButton() => InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If I use the solution specified here [User control with custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10187377/3605220) I get this problem [Wpf - Custom control: How to override default properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51836773/3605220).

So, there is a solution that avoid both problems?

Comment: Your `TargetType` of `ControlTemplate` is incorrect. It should be MyButton.

Comment: I added xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" and TargetType="local:MyButton" but now it says "ArgumentException: 'MyButton' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'UserControl'."

Comment: Update: `ArgumentException: 'MyButton' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'UserControl'.` seems only a rendering problem of the editor.
When I build my application and run it, it works correctly: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32025549/51704838-580d0e80-201a-11e9-9a52-72d4ee28b62c.jpg
Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom Button should not be a UserControl, but instead directly derive from Button.

Add a "Custom Control (WPF)" to you Visual Studio Project and modify it like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(MyButton));

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then change its default Style in the generated `Themes\Generic.xaml` file:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButton">
                <Border Name="ground"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                    <Label Name="content"
                           VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                           Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                           FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) for details.